# Hasura permission based on latest row from array relationship

Tags: database-design, hasura

I am using Hasura to build a GraphQL API. It's coming along nicely but I have a permissions related problem.

I am looking for a way to have a permission based on a field value from the latest row of a multi row table.

So I have created an array relationship which I would like to use in a permission. But I am only interested in the latest row from this array. Permissions allow me to use the `_in` or `_nin` operators on the array. But I specifically need the value from the latest row. As far as I know there is no such operator for this.

When there is only one row in the table then using the `_eq` operator on the field works. But the chances or there being only one row in the table is very low.

Here's some simplified information about my tables and relationships:

### Tables

#### jobs

| id | title | status (array relationship) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job title 1 |  |
| 2 | Job title 2 |  |

#### jobs_status

| id | job_id | datetime | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 'open' |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | 'closed' |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-03 | 'open' |

#### jobs_responses

| id | job_id | response | job (object relationship) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | response A |  |
| 1 | 2 | response B |  |
| 1 | 2 | response C |  |

### Relationships

```
jobs.status (Array): jobs (id) -> jobs_status (job_id)
jobs_responses.job (Object): jobs_responses (job_id) -> jobs (id)
```

### Permission

The permission I created is an insert permission on the `jobs_responses` table which uses the `job` relationship to check the value of the `job.status` field. But since this is an array I would like to only check the status value of the latest row (sorted by datetime). The `_eq`, `_in` or `_nin` operators cannot do that.

### What I tried

I tried making an Object relationship for `jobs.status` instead of an Array relationship. But that only returns the first row that matches the relationship.

I thought about creating a normal `jobs.status` field in the `jobs` table that can be used for the permission. The `jobs_status` table would still exist but would not be used for the permission. The `jobs.status` field would have the same value as the `status` field in the latest row of `jobs_status`. Both the `jobs.status` field and `jobs_status` table would be populated at the same time when creating/updating a job. But I don't really like this solution because it feels like a double administration.

Does anyone know if Hasura can handle my use case?
Would love to read how you would solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably solve this using a [Computed Field](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/computed-fields/).

You would have to define a function that fetches the latest `status` given a `jobs` row argument. Then you would define a computed field `latest_job_status` on `jobs` referencing this function.

Now you can refer to this computed field in permissions like you would any other field, and you don't have to manually ensure that the field is kept up to date whenever changes are made to the `jobs_status` table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I created after the answer from @plc.

Leaving it here so it might help others:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.jobs_status(job_row jobs)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    SELECT status FROM jobs_status WHERE job_id=job_row.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: I have appended your answer to mine because I thank that is better form on StackOverflow. You can remove your answer if you like.

Comment: @plc https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156239/997587, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388037/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262210/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541

Comment: @starball Thanks. I've removed my own edit.